# Make CISCO RVS4000 into hub mode

Tags: switch, wireshark, hub

I am trying to do packet analysis with a RVS4000 Cisco device that has four computers connected. The device is not broadcasting packets to the other devices connected to the device.

For my lab, I have two computers, one running Wireshark and the other creating packets. I want to be able to view the packets on the second computer.

Is there a way to turn the device into more of a hub than a switch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the term you are looking for is "Port Mirroring".

> Port Mirroring is a feature used to send a copy of network packets to a network monitoring connection. Port mirroring sends traffic from one port to another without interfering because it has the ability to copy the traffic from a single port to a mirror port. This process is commonly used for network appliances that are required to monitor network traffic, and analyze and debug data or diagnose errors on a network. Port Mirroring on the RVS4000 helps monitor traffic destined to a particular port.

Cisco provides documentation on how to set it up and use it for your model:

[Configuration of Port Mirroring on RVS4000](http://sbkb.cisco.com/CiscoSB/GetArticle.aspx?docid=b5a661c9aefc4f5eae57e5ceffa773e6_Configuration_of_Port_Mirroring_feature_on_RVS4000_series_4_.xml)

1. Log in to the web configuration utility and choose L2 Switch > Port Mirroring. The Port Mirroring page opens.

[image]

2. Check the Mirror Source check box for the desired port. Traffic on this port is copied to the Mirror Port.

[image]

3. Choose the appropriate destination port from the Mirror Port drop down list.

[image]

4. Click Save to save the Port Mirroring settings.